# UIButton Function add Tap Style

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I Have written a function in Swift 4 which creates a button that receives the `UIButton`, a Color and a String for the title. I would like to add to this function a highlight or tap *style* but I am not sure how.

The function:

```
 func homeBtn(button: UIButton, color: UIColor, title: String){
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(color, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: "Raleway-Medium", size: 24)
    button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    button.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
    button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(20,20,20,20)
    button.layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
    button.layer.borderWidth = 2
    button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.width/2
    button.layer.backgroundColor = whiteColor.cgColor
 }
```

The button is a circle and has a String centered in the middle with the `UIColor` being used as an outline. Can someone show me how to add a tap style to this function that uses the same `UIColor` to fill in the button and turn the text white please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the title color you can easily do this without adding events.

```
button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .highlighted)
button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
```

For the background color you need to define the following events:

```
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchDown(button:)), for: .touchDown)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUpInside(button:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Define functions - You can refer additional touch types as well - see `UIControlEvents`

```
@objc func touchDown(button: UIButton) {
    guard let borderColor = button.layer.borderColor else {
        return
    }
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(cgColor: borderColor)
}

@objc func touchUpInside(button: UIButton) {
    // Set backgroundColor for normal state...
}
```